# How to dynamically populate ExpandableListView through user input?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm building a GPA tracker app and I find that an ExpandableListView is the most appropriate thing to use.  The function is this:

The user clicks on a FAB button and adds a Semester (group/header).
The user clicks on the generated Semester (group/header) and adds a course.

I can add the groups but I couldn't figure out how to dynamically add children for those groups.  Basically, I want to get the ID of the clicked group, start an alertDialog to have the user input the course information and add that information to a List.

I tried to do that with the `setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener())` method but now I can't expand the group.  This wasn't my final implementation anyways.  I really just wanted to get this logic to work.

These are the Lists and HashMaps that contain my Semester and Course information:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String>listCourses = new ArrayList<>();
    private String semester, course;
```

This is where I am adding my Semesters (group/header)

```
private void addSemester() {
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.parent_dialog_layout, null);
        final EditText et_semester = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_semester);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Create A Semester");
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                semester = et_semester.getText().toString();
                listDataHeader.add(semester);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        builder.show();
    }
```

And in my `onCreate()`, I'm calling my `setOnGroupClickListener` method to add the children:

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, final int groupPosition, long id) {
                parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

                View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.child_dialog_layout, null);
                final EditText et_course = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_course);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Create A Course");
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                builder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        course = et_course.getText().toString();
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition), listCourses);
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                builder.show();

                return true;
            }

            });
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

I want to access the clicked group's ID and then add my children to that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call **notifyDataSetChanged();** inside your Dialog's interface OnClickListener:

> ```
>                 builder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
>                     course = et_course.getText().toString();
>                     listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition), listCourses);
>                     notifyDataSetChanged();
>                 }
>             });
> ```

Comment: I'm going to implement this once I get back on my laptop but my code overrides the group click action from expanding the group to showing an alert dialog.  Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: To go around what? do you mean to get rid of the code overriding the group's click action for showing the alert?

Comment: I meant that I can't expand my group now since whenever I click, it just shows the alert dialog.

Comment: I noticed that I forgot to upvote this answer. If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?